# amplify ssl configuration stuck

Tags: amazon-web-services

I've got my domain listed on route 53 and I have a frontend site hosted via amplify. However It's been "configuring ssl" for over a day now. I'm not really sure whats going on.

Are these all the steps I need to take?

[image: image 1]
[image: image 2]
[image: image 3]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you confirm the domain is working by pinging it, if it resolved correctly, please remove it and it again

Comment: yes this is what I expected that's why i asked you to ping the domain

Answer (score 4):

Wanted to add some info on how I found the issue with the help of the above answer from AWS PS

I transferred my domain from another registrar(namecheap). The nameservers hadden't been changed yet. So do this

1. Go to Route 53
2. On the left, find registered domains
3. Click your domain and find name servers
4. Make sure your nameservers are pointed to AWS nameservers

Answer (score 4):

I had same issue after moving from Google Domains to AWS. I hadn't updated my name servers and they were still point to the google domains one. Replacing the name servers in Route 53 (under the domains tab) with the items listed in the NS record for the hosted zone of that domain ended up resolving it. I did have to delete and remake the custom domain in the Amplify console, but once you generate it it handles everything else automatically.